# Why does my profile photo thumbnail fail to fully load?

Tags: support, profile-picture, imgur

The issue is a bit silly, but still, would be nice to have it fixed. My profile photo seems to load perfectly fine on my profile page and in the top dashboard. Yet, when I am looking at my posts (Questions, Answers) then my miniature photo does not fully load, it only loads the upper half. I did empty the cache and accessed from different browsers. Yet, the problem seems to persist. Other users don't seem to have the same issue. Does it have something to do with the profile picture file itself? Wrong format, size? Many thanks!

Update: It seems to work on Meta StackOverflow. Yet it doesn't work on Chess StackExchange.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what you mean please?

Comment: @ProgramFOX Great idea! I added a screenshot. Cheers.

Comment: I can also see the problem on [one of your chess answers](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4611/1-e4-e6-2-nc3-how-should-black-respond/4612#4612) so it's not local to your system

Comment: @psubsee2003 I am not sure this is a caching issue, since the thumbnail tries to load the correct photo, yet fails to load it completely / that particular copy is corrupt.

Comment: @RauanSagit try to re-upload your profile picture. Any luck? The thing is, imgur is creating several thumbnails on the fly when image is uploaded. Looks like the specific 32x32 thumb is indeed corrupted, so another try should fix it. :)

Comment: Quick test show it's indeed not permanent issue, [this one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/joIQD.png?s=32) is just fine.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yep, it seems fine indeed. Well, then I guess the best thing I can do is wait.

Comment: No no, don't wait... re-upload the picture in chess.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Amazing. It worked. Thanks!

Comment: OK then, it was a temporary hiccup in imgur side. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you upload a picture, imgur creates several thumbnails on the fly.

It looks like the specific 32x32 thumbnails has indeed been corrupted due to some temporary hiccup on the imgur servers.

Re-uploading the picture in the relevant site should "fix" the problem and create a new thumbnail.

Comment: What is the ideal size for stackexchange to upload?

Comment: @Neocortex no ideal size, just ideal ratio of 1:1.